# Android Fragment Content Lost

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a problem on android eclipse with fragments in a viewpager. When an home activity starts i show an actionbar tabs and first fragment on the screen. When i swipe to next fragment and then back to first fragment, first fragment contents are still on the screen. But on the other hand if a swipe 2 times to right and go back first fragment, its contents are lost and blank screen is shown. My codes are below. How to retain each fragment content either it is shown or is visible ? any help is appreciated. Thanx in advance.

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

private String[] menuItems = null;
private ActionBar bar = null;
private ViewPager viewPager = null;
private TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(10);
    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuTitles);
    bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(menuItems[i]),
                    NewsFeedActivity.class, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(menuItems[i]),
                    NotificationActivity.class, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(menuItems[i]),
                    NewsFeedActivity.class, null);
            break;
        case 3:
            tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(menuItems[i]),
                    NotificationActivity.class, null);
            break;
        case 4:
            tabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(menuItems[i]),
                    NewsFeedActivity.class, null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore selected tab
    int saved = savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0);
    if (saved != getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex())
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(saved);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "gokay!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

}
```

}

**NewsFeedActivity.java**

```
public class NewsFeedActivity extends Fragment {

static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
private ArrayList<String> xmlList = null;
private XMLParser parser = null;
private String xml = "";
private Document doc = null;
private NodeList nl = null;
private View view = null;
private Element e = null;
private ListView listNewsFeed = null;
private static Bundle args = null;
private static NewsFeedActivity newsFeed = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

public static NewsFeedActivity newInstance(int page, String title) {
    newsFeed = new NewsFeedActivity();
    args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("Page", page);
    args.putString("newsFeed", title);
    newsFeed.setArguments(args);
    return newsFeed;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_feed, container, false);
    if (getActivity().getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition() == 0) {
        new NewsFeeder().execute("");
    }
    return view;
}

private class NewsFeeder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Haber kaynağı yenileniyor..");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        xmlList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            parser = new XMLParser();
            xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Log.i("gokay", xml);
            doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("gokay", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            xmlList.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            xmlList.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            xmlList.add("Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            xmlList.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        }

        listNewsFeed = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, xmlList);
        listNewsFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
        // onFoodMenuItemsDBAddFinished();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in oncreate() fragment